# how to print a long string in multiple lines of specific width dynamically in php

Tags: php, css, laravel-4

i want to `echo` my string into multiple lines,the lines has some specific width and each line must be underlined.i used the wardwrap function,but it takes the no of characters for breaking into new lines,but I want it should be fixed by the line width.
my PHPcode is

```
    <p>
       <u>
         <b>Uitgevoerde werkzaamheden</b>{{wordwrap($werkbon_report->work_preformed,190,"\n",TRUE)}}
       </u>
    </p>
```

my CSS code is

```
p.test
{
 width:82em; 
 word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

but it is not limited by the line width,it is limited by the no of characters.

Comment: try nl2br() if there is new line character in string

Comment: it accepts a string,which may or maynot have a new line character,but should be displayed as a multiline string,where each line looks like a row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this- edit third parameter value

```
{{wordwrap($werkbon_report->work_preformed,190,"<br>\n",TRUE)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't know how wide (px, em) characters are, so you can't truncate a string by a measure width. This should be solved with CSS only. Simply print out the entire string in the `<p>` and then style the `<p>` to have a fixed width. The text will wrap within it... You don't need the `<u>` tag. In fact, you should avoid using the `<u>` tag along with `<i>` and `<b>`. Use CSS instead.

```
<p class="test">{{{ $some_text }}}</p>

p.test {
    text-decoration: underline;
    width: 82em;
}
```